# How to check if any sys.argv argument equals a specific string in Python

Tags: python-2.7, argv

In Python I would like to check if *any* argument that has been passed to my script equals "-h" (so that I can display a help banner and exit).

Should I loop through sys.argv values or is there a more simple way to achieve this?

Comment: `Should I loop through sys.argv values` - Yes. Its not only for `argv`, if it is a sequence you have to loop to find it, either internally or explicitly.

Comment: `sys.argv` is *just a list*. You'll have to loop through that sequence *at some point*, yes.

Comment: If you use `argparse` it will provide help for you.

Answer (score 6):

Just check if the desired string exists in the list:

```
import sys

if "__main__" == __name__:
    if "-h" in sys.argv:
        print "This is a help text."
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys

def help_required():
    return "-h" in sys.argv[1:]
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you are aiming to do is to search for `-h` in the arguments then you can just iterate over the `sys.argv` list and see if you find that value.

However it looks like the problem you are *actually* trying to solve is to create a parser for your command line arguments. If that's the case I think the best approach is to just use the [argparse module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) which is designed  to solve exactly this problem and avoid re-inventing the wheel. By default `argparse` adds a help option with `-h` or `--help`. (However that default behaviour can be changed if need be, see the part of the docs that deals with that: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#add-help)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with what lebeef and dlask mentioned. i would prefer to use fileinput and it is more sophcicated. You can import fileinput

```
import fileinput
if "-h" in fileinput.input():
   display_help_text()
```